# listview with table layout

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

i am developing one activity in which i use list view with table lay out .
I want to display images and text in that list view ,but the problem is that the images are display slightly out of list order like

```
 img1        text1                              img1    text1
  img2       text2     and i want this          img2    text2
 img3        text3                              img3    text3
 img4        text4                              img4    text4
 img5        text5                              img5    text5
```

this way.. so any idea about the property of list view or image view to set it in order properly ? then plz comment...

**list_row.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="2dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
         android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use the above code. According to your requirement, Tablelayout is not required at all.

Comment: @autocrat ya no need to require.

Comment: @Andrain ya i have tried it. do you want to show me that result in image

Comment: I dont think so that you have tried this code because just look at your imageView tag .. it contains 2 times with same parameter that is `android:layout_gravity` .

Comment: Its ohk ..~! **Be Careful** when u r going to help someone. @Tamilan

Answer (score 0):

Try following code into your tablelayout

```
<TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dip" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: You can set gravity as per your need @Jigs Patel

Answer (score 0):

****Item_List.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/WHITE_BACKGROUND"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textStyle="normal|italic" />

            </TableLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="2dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/featureListImageRight"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_right" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


**Main.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WHITE_BACKGROUND"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0">

<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/WHITE_BACKGROUND" >

 </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```